# Insert text using css @keyframe

Tags: css, css-animations

I'm trying to get text inserted into a `div` or `p` tag. `@keyframe` code will change the text but disregards the rest of the code. i.e I want a box around the text as a certain size but the box is only as big as the text itself. I've tried with and without `::before`/`::after`. No joy. The animation works fine without the `content` line in the rule. The box appears and changes size and colour as it's coded to.

```css
.animate::before {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: steelblue;
  animation: sizingAnimation 3s infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: 2;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards !important;
  content: "interim";
}

@keyframes sizingAnimation {
  from {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    content: "hello";
  }
  to {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    border: 2px solid red;
    background-color: bisque;
    content: "goodbye";
    font-size: 50px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p class="animate"></p>
</div>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/forexbob/pen/WNaZqbX)

I got scolded last time I posted so hopefully this post meets standards. Complete newbie so go easy on me.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`display:block` (or inline-block if you need it inline) would do the trick

```css
.animate::before {
  display:block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: steelblue;
  animation: sizingAnimation 3s infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: 2;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards !important;
  content: "interim";
}

@keyframes sizingAnimation {
  from {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    content: "hello";
  }
  to {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    border: 2px solid red;
    background-color: bisque;
    content: "goodbye";
    font-size: 50px;
  }
}
```

```html
<p class="animate"></p>
```